# Best way to filter results of One To Many relation query. MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, inner-join, one-to-many

Is multiple joins use is a good idea to filter query results by multiple attribute values? For example:

```
product
--------
pid desc 
--------
1   prod1
2   prod2

attrib
--------
pid  aid val
--------
1    1   "avalue1"
1    2   "avalue2"
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN attrib a1 ON (p.pid=a1.pid)
INNER JOIN attrib a2 (p.pid=a2.pid)
WHERE a1.aid=1 and a1.val="avalue1" and a2.aid=2 and a2.val="avalue2"
```

Or there is a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `join` method definitely works, and it can take advantage of indexes.  However, I prefer aggregation with `having` because it is more flexible:

```
select p.*
from product p join
     attrib a
     on p.pid = a.pid
group by p.pid
having sum(a.aid = 1 and a.val = 'avalue1') > 0 and
       sum(a.aid = 2 and a.val = 'avalue2') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of attributes that meet one of the conditions.  It is easy to add another condition, positive or negative.  For instance, to revise the above to require the absence of 3/avalue3:

```
select p.*
from product p join
     attrib a
     on p.pid = a.pid
group by p.pid
having sum(a.aid = 1 and a.val = 'avalue1') > 0 and
       sum(a.aid = 2 and a.val = 'avalue2') > 0 and
       sum(a.aid = 3 and a.val = 'avalue3') = 0;
```